# Rails + Postgres Inner Join with aggregates issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, inner-join

This type of question is all over the place... but here's my issue.

I have rails models: `Organization`, `Activity`, `Donation`, `DonationItem`. I'm trying to get the summation of `Activity.hours` and `DonationItem.amount` for each `Organization`.

I can't use the straight relations (ex: `Organization.activities.pluck(:hours).sum` because I'm in a situation where a `Organization.select("...").group(...)` must be used.

Current rails joins are below, though they're obviously incorrect at this stage:

```
 @relation = Organization.joins(:activities, donations: :donation_items)
                         .select("organizations.id, sum(activities.hours), sum(donation_items.amount)")
                         .group("organizations.id")
```

This is the SQL structure (basically...) + select is located here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fb932e/6

Here's the select for peoples that wish to not view the SQL Fiddle

```
select 
        o.id,
        sum(a.hours) as "hours", 
        sum(di.amount) as "amount"
    from organizations o
    inner join activities a 
        on a.organization_id = o.id
    inner join donations d 
        on d.organization_id = o.id
    inner join donation_items di
        on di.donation_id = d.id
    group by o.id
;
```

I understand what the problem is, just not the solution to solving it...

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL you can use `CTE` or sub-clause to resolve issue of incorrect values for hours and amount, but not sure how would you transform these in rails query builder

Using CTE

```
with organization_activity as (
  select organization_id, sum(hours) as "hours"
  from activities
  group by organization_id 
)
select 
        o.id,
        a.hours as "hours", 
        sum(di.amount) as "amount"
    from organizations o
    inner join organization_activity a 
        on a.organization_id = o.id
    inner join donations d 
        on d.organization_id = o.id
    inner join donation_items di
        on di.donation_id = d.id
    group by o.id, a.hours
;
```

Using sub-clause

```
select 
        o.id,
        a.hours as "hours", 
        sum(di.amount) as "amount"
    from organizations o
    inner join (
      select organization_id, sum(hours) as "hours"
      from activities
      group by organization_id
    ) a 
        on a.organization_id = o.id
    inner join donations d 
        on d.organization_id = o.id
    inner join donation_items di
        on di.donation_id = d.id
    group by o.id, a.hours
;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fb932e/11)